# How to change windows logon background by code

Tags: windows, background-image

I would like to set programatically a background image for the windows logon screen.

How can I do that ?

Prefered language is C# but I can read other languages and adapt :)

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

Try read this link.
http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-windows-7-logon-screen-easily-without-using-hacks-tools/
In the program, you must make creating of one directory and copy JPG file to this directory.